# Use alpha numeric with with hyphen and underscore

Tags: regex

I've created the following regex which is not working to support the following.
1.accept alpha numreic with hyphen '-' and underscore only 
2.can start only with alpha 
3.can end with space

I try with the following and its not working.
any idea?

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9][\da-z-.]*[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your conditions, the following regex is what you want:

`^[a-zA-Z][\w-]*\s*$`